How to improve autofocus perfomance when focussing at birds flying at large distances in bright sky?
While photographing terns at a beach with my Nikon D7200 and Sigma 150-600, autofocus frequently fails, resulting in blurry images or focusing on the bright sky instead. This setup works fine for similar distances inland. Is there an AF calibration or technique adjustment that can improve this setup for such scenarios?

If your lens is compatible with the USB dock, you can program custom focus limit ranges for the C1/C2 options. I.e. you could set it to only focus between 10-30 meters (or whatever is suitable); rather than the default ranges the limiter switch gives.
Otherwise prefocusing at the expected distance can help. And know that the camera will almost always search for focus out to infinity before it starts searching back towards the camera (there's several reasons for that).

For subjects as distant animal life, your lens will be working at infinity focus. Best you use manual focus. Set the focus in advance adjusting focus on a distant tree or building or mountain, or cloud. Do this and use a fast shutter, and you will succeed.
